# Timing learning Drools

Tags: drools, drools-flow

I'm making a thesis on Drools. But I have no idea on the workloard learning Drools. Could someone give a number from 1 to 10 on Expert, Flow, Fusion and Guvnor. I just have to test the technique on a simple Java example.
thanks, Els

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you only need Expert if your doing a simple Java example.

If I would gives scores to the modules I would say:

- Expert 8
- Fusion 1
- Flow 3
- Guvnor 4

Now how long does 8 take? I don't know depends what your background is :) This is an estimate, but gives you some idea. Expert is the first step and will take the most time. After that Fusion is a fast one. Flow and Guvnor can take longer.

I suggest that you read the drools manual parts for Introduction and Expert and download the Drools code examples from the [Drools website](http://www.jboss.org/drools/downloads). Expert docs explain some of the examples. Play with the examples, break them, add new features and you will see how Drools works.

Comment: Expert requires nothing. Fusion requires Expert. Flow (= jBPM 5 now) requires nothing. Guvnor requires Expert. Planner requires Expert.